# How can I auto-include multiple navigations in model?

Tags: postgresql, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

EF Core 6 introduced the ability to auto-include navigations (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#model-configuration-for-auto-including-navigations).I have a model that is related to multiple tables and I would like to configure it to auto-include multiple related tables but have been unable to figure out how to do it. Is this supported?

This is the current setup.

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<ExampleModel>()
            .UseXminAsConcurrencyToken()
            .Navigation(e => e.ExampleModelRelatedItem1).AutoInclude()
            .AutoInclude();
```

I have tried variations such as

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<ExampleModel>()
            .UseXminAsConcurrencyToken()
            .Navigation(e => e.ExampleModelRelatedItem1).AutoInclude()
            .Navigation(e => e.ExampleModelRelatedItem2).AutoInclude()
            .AutoInclude();
```

but can't find anything that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are thinking that the whole configuration should be with *single* fluent API call chain.

Which is true for fluent APIs that return the `EntityTypeBuilder<T>` (from `ModelBuilder.Entity<T>()` call) they are called on.

However many configuration APIs (like `Property`, `Navigation`, `HasMany`, `HasOne`, `OwnsOne`, `OwnsMany` etc.) return different builder providing specific fluent APIs for it.

So what you need is to simply "restart" the fluent chain. This could be done in several way. For instance, with another `Entity<T>()` call

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<ExampleModel>()
    .UseXminAsConcurrencyToken();

modelBuilder.Entity<ExampleModel>()
    .Navigation(e => e.ExampleModelRelatedItem1).AutoInclude();

modelBuilder.Entity<ExampleModel>()
    .Navigation(e => e.ExampleModelRelatedItem2).AutoInclude();
```

or with `Entity<T>()` overload with builder action

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<ExampleModel>(builder =>
{
    builder.UseXminAsConcurrencyToken();

    builder.Navigation(e => e.ExampleModelRelatedItem1).AutoInclude();

    builder.Navigation(e => e.ExampleModelRelatedItem2).AutoInclude();
});
```

or using local variable

```cs
{
    var builder = modelBuilder.Entity<ExampleModel>();

    builder.UseXminAsConcurrencyToken();

    builder.Navigation(e => e.ExampleModelRelatedItem1).AutoInclude();

    builder.Navigation(e => e.ExampleModelRelatedItem2).AutoInclude();
}
```

or private or local method receiving `EntityTypeBuilder<T>`, or class implementing `IEntityTypeConfiguration<T>` with `Apply` method receiving the same, etc.

The essential is to configure each navigation (`AutoInclude` or whatever) separately by starting with `Navigation` method from `EnityTypeBuilder<T>` obtained somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Of course the `.AutoInclude()` implementation has a more complex logic but under the hood it uses the `.SetIsEagerLoaded(bool?)` method.

Here is an extension method that could be a good starting point.
It's kind of 'brute force' as it tries to find a navigation for each and every property of the entity.

```cs
public static void AutoInclude(this IMutableEntityType entityType)
{
    var entityClrTypes =
        entityType
            .Model
            .GetEntityTypes()
            .Select(entityType => entityType.ClrType)
            .ToList();

    entityType
        .GetProperties()
        .Where(
            entityType =>
            entityClrTypes.Contains(entityType.ClrType)
        )
        .Select(
            entityProperty =>
            entityType.FindNavigation(entityProperty.Name) // can be null
        )
        .OfType<IMutableNavigation>() // filter null
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(navigation => navigation.SetIsEagerLoaded(true));
}

// Usage
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>(
    entityTypeBuilder =>
    entityTypeBuilder.Metadata.AutoInclude()
);

// Usage for your example
modelBuilder
    .Entity<ExampleModel>(
        entityTypeBuilder =>
        entityTypeBuilder.Metadata.AutoInclude()
    )
    .UseXminAsConcurrencyToken()
```

Hope that helps.